# having issues with the bot logging/connecting to discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so im having this issue with my bot, which has never happened up to now.
it shows:
`aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [The semaphore timeout period has expired]`

my python version is 3.10.11

discord.py version is 2.3.2

ive tried:
uninstalling then reinstalling discord.py

someone said it was my internet connection so i changed which wifi i was
using

changing the discord bot token

using a different bot

i would show the full traceback here but it won't let me post the question with all the code/traceback
https://paste.pythondiscord.com/EKNA
removed my token code from here

(ik i shouldn't be using a link and show the code here but im not able to so bear with me)
i have no antivirus or firewall blocking my python program

Comment: Did you re-generate your token and tried again?

Comment: @Dominik yes, still didn't work